# is it safe? insert the data to db by user ..?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm tring to make the visitor can register from the front end or (the index page )not admin page ..

firstly , I made the template page , it is name : Register User

but I am afraid if the user can do somthing bad (sql injection .. etc) ..

this is my code ..

```
if(!empty($_POST['user_name']) || !empty($_POST['email'])){
$user_login  = $_POST['user_name'];
$user_email  = $_POST['email'];
$random_password = wp_generate_password(5 , true );
wp_create_user( $user_login, $random_password, $user_email )

} else {
echo 'The user name or E-mail is empty';

}
```

also , how can know this is email or not ?

sorry , my language is bad >_<

Comment: Read this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the already included function in wordpress:

Details here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_email

`is_email()`

```
<?php if ( is_email( 'email@domain.com' ) ) {
      echo 'email address is valid.';
} ?>
```

Might also want to validate the 'username' using the function `username_exists()`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/username_exists

```
<?php  
       $username = $_POST['username'];
       if ( username_exists( $username ) )
           echo "Username In Use!";
       else
           echo "Username Not In Use!";
?>
```

Comment: great function .. I don't know about it before .. it is very great .. thank you jakub ..

Comment: also this is very important , I was to write a sql string if the username is exist or not .. but the function is very easy to use also great .. Thank you alot my friend Jakub ^_^

Comment: glad to help, enjoy! Always if working with wordpress refer to the codec to save valuable time!

Comment: thank you , in the next time I will go to codex before ask .. ^_^

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the `wp_create_user` function - is it sanitizing/escaping the data for you? If not, you may need to do it yourself (see [mysql_real_escape_string](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php))

Comment: aha , great .. maybe I will using mysql_real escape string

Answer (score 3):

The wp_create_user function should be safe to just send user-input to.

The second part is answered by Jakub